# Connect to SQL Server CE from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have a program which I deploy to an emulator from Visual Studio. At first launch the program create a database on the emulator.

Is the any ability to connect to this database from my computer? I don't need a program code and I am searching for ready solution (VS tool or a separate utility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the [SQL Server CE Toolbox](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/) into Visual Studio and enjoy all its features!

Read [this blog post on Erik EJ's web site](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2012/08/sql-server-compact-toolbox-31visual.html) on the very latest features of version 3.1

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use it with VS 2008?  I can not convert my project to VS 2010.

Comment: See [Erik EJ's long list of SQL Server Compact related tools](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html) - if there *is* something out there - he's definitely got it on his list!

Answer (score 1):

The only tool I'm aware of that allows a desktop machine to connect to a SQL Compact database on a separate device is [Primeworks' DataPortConsole](http://primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html).  If you can pull it locally, then SQLCE Toolbox (see marc_s's answer) is a great tool.

**EDIT**

Not to be outdone by marc_s's fancy graphics, here's one of the DataPortConsole. :)

[image]